# How to use Solr in Spring MVC Application

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, solr, solrj

I am new to Solr and I want to use it with Spring MVC Application which is using an existing MySQL database. I have some questions :

- Is we have to save in both place i.e MySQL and Solr ;
- or I have to linked the MySQL with Solr using data import handler and which will be fast and be-finical;
- Is Solr core/collection will be linked with single table mean suppose I have 4 tables then I have create the 4 core/collection.

Can any please let me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is we have to save in both place i.e MySQL and Solr

*Its depends on you. But  I would say yes. You have to save data at both places. Mysql will be used by your application and I Assume solr will be used for searching the data(As is been implemented by me)*

or I have to linked the MySQL with Solr using data import handler and which will be fast and be-finical;

*I think you have to link Mysql with solr using data-import in order to have the data on solr. If your mysql itself does not have any existing  data then you can directly convert your data in json format and dump it to Solr.*

Is Solr core/collection will be linked with single table mean suppose I have 4 tables then I have create the 4 core/collection.

*It depends on your requirement. You can store 4 tables data in seperate 4 cores and 4 tables data in single core. For this you need to configure your query in data-config.xml which will be used by solr data-import.*

Comment: Can you please help me how to create 4  table in single core and manage via spring-data-solr.

Comment: Suppose I have created the four table in single then how we have fetch single table data ?

Comment: You have to write a query which will have a join with four tables(if they have any relationship) and add the query to the data-config.xml and start indexing...I dont know how to manage the same via spring-data-solr...